# How do I sort associated data?

Tags: php, cakephp

I know how to sort the primary model using the 'order' option. But how do I sort associated data?

Ok, I tried this:

```
$task = $this->Task->read(null, $id, array('order' =>
        array('Subtask.completed ASC')
));
```

Then I found out that read doesn't have an option parameter. So I tried setting a variable for the other model, so I could use the option in the find method:

```
$subtasks = $this->Subtask->find('all', array('conditions' => array(
        'Subtask.task_id' => $id),
        'order' => array('Subtask.completed ASC')
));
```

Which got me the following error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\taskExplorer\app\controllers\tasks_controller.php on line 54

So a solution to the problem might be to bind in a second model (Subtask) so I can use it for find. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Damn this cursed infliction... why, why must we work blindly... (AKA, please post some code)

Comment: This question will get closed in it's current state. Add some code and tell us what you've tried.

Comment: Please post some code and specially be more descriptive on the problem that you are facing.

Comment: When you improve the question to include more about your problem, as well as your current attempt, flag this for a moderator to be reopened.

Comment: Is that enough? Can you reopen this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
$this->loadModel('Subtask');
$subtasks = $this->Subtask->find('all', array('conditions' => array(
    'Subtask.task_id' => $id),
    'order' => array('Subtask.completed ASC')
));
```

And if you have defined relationship in model then you can access it like:

```
$subtasks = $this->Task->Subtask->find(
                             //rest of code
                           );
```